# Why can't i put my background image in drawable v24 folder?

Tags: android-drawable

I stored my background image for my relative layout in drawable xxxhdpi and i read somewhere the v24 folder provides device compatibility (i.e. to manage different screen densities in android) and different android versions,
but when i put that image in the v24 folder i get this error Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.vince_mp3player.mp3player:drawable/redpinkgradientbackground" (7f06006a) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06006a a=-1 r=0x7f06006a}

I'm new to android studio so i don't really know what those different drawable folders mean, where do i put my images and where do i put my icons?

Thanks, 
-Vince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know detail about your error but if you're trying to add

1. Image (create a folder name drawable-resolution)
2. Icon (create a folder called minimap-resolution)

In your case create new folder by 
Right click on res -> Android Resource Directory

Directory Name -> drawable-xxxhdpi
Resource Type -> drawable

Simply add drag & drop your high resolution images to that folder. [Learn supporting screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing)